# Changing box color after random seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a java script code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        #myDiv {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: red;
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function setColor(){
    var x = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var y='#';
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    y = y+x[Math.round(Math.random()*15)];
}
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor=y;
}

var myVar = setInterval(function(){setColor()}, 1000);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It's changing the box color each after 1 second but I want to change color after random seconds. Say first time after 1 sec then after .5 sec, after that 5 sec & so on. I don't want to refresh the page to do it. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Javascript Function

This function should do the trick for you:

```
function doSomething() {}

(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000 - 500)) + 500;
    setTimeout(function() {
            //alert('A');
            doSomething();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
```

It will `doSomething()` at random intervals :)

[here's the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9GyyA/184/) - simply remove the "//" from the alert to see it in action! :)

---

## Using your example

This [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9GyyA/188/) uses your function for changing the colour of your div :)

**Edit**

## Explaination

the first line: (to get rand)

```
// Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
// and so you will get a random number between the max and min values
```

the second line ( setTimeout)

```
setTimeout(function() { 
//call this function
```

the loop();

```
loop(); // this is using a recursive method function and so the whole method is called again/ over and over
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working very well. But for me, it's difficult to understand. Can you please explain it's algorithm. How it is working? Please!!!!!!!

Comment: please see edit. Pretty much it is a [recursive algorithm](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/content/recursive_alg/rec_alg.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you can't just access a string character like an array in javascript, use `.charAt()` method instead.

```
var hex = x.charAt(Math.round(Math.random()*15)),
    color = '#' + hex + hex + hex;
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor=color;
```